# Facebook SDK for Android - Example app won't work

Tags: android, facebook

Okey, I've done all the business, followed all the steps, but still can't get it to work.
The simple Example app that comes with the Facebook SDK, is working on the emulator and on devices with android 1.5.
So my guess is the single login thing.

If I'm right then I should generate a key hash and I've been told that the right debug keystore is placed under

> C:\Users\xxx.android\debug.keystore

so I followed the tutorial.

Downloaded OpenSSL from google.code and in the terminal I write something like:

> "C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_22\bin\keytool.exe" -exportcert -alias
>   androiddebugkey -keystore
>   "C:\Users\JoeZ.android\debug.keystore"|"C:\Users\xxx\Downloads\openssl-0.9.8k_X64\bin\openssl.exe"
>   sha1
>   -binary|"C:\Users\xxx\Downloads\openssl-0.9.8k_X64\bin\openssl.exe" base64

and I get a nice key which I inserted into the Android Key Hash box in facebook, I've tried both with or without the = sign after the output but nothing seems to work.

I just get invalid_key when I try to sign into the Example application.
I even tried a signed application but it did not work.
And if I'm not mistaken the only thing to write in the Example application is my APP_ID, right?

I'm having the exact same problem with my own application that I'm developing. So please can anybody help me?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

If the keytool command doesn't work for you, I found a way around that stuff: you can just reverse engineer which key to put as Key Hash in the Facebook Developer section. Within your Activity just print out the Key Hash by doing:

```
try {
   PackageInfo info = getPackageManager().getPackageInfo("[your package name, e.g. com.yourcompany.yourapp]", PackageManager.GET_SIGNATURES);
   for (Signature signature : info.signatures) {
        MessageDigest md = MessageDigest.getInstance("SHA");
        md.update(signature.toByteArray());
        Log.d("Hash Key:", Base64.encode(md.digest()));
   }
} catch (NameNotFoundException e) {

} catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e) {

}
```

This worked for me. The MessageDigest class is included in the JDK. The Base64 class not. You can use [this one](http://iharder.sourceforge.net/current/java/base64/) for example.

Comment: Works like a charm on my app :-) +1

Comment: This doesn't work for me.  I get the error "The method encode(ByteBuffer, ByteBuffer) in the type Base64 is not applicable for the arguments (byte[])" over Base64.encode(md.digest()));  Figured it out, had to change to encodeBytes

Answer (score 5):

I had a similar problem. For me, it was resolved when I uninstalled the latest update of the Facebook app and now only have the native Facebook app v1.2.
(Means, when I go into the market and search for Facebook, the "Facebook for Android" would be displayed as 'not installed' on my device).

On my Nexus One (Android 2.2.1), when I had the latest Facebook app installed, there was not 'uninstall app' buton, only a 'Uninstall latest updates', which is what I did. In fact, I can't even uninstall the entire Facebook (now v1.2) app for whatever reason, the uninstall button is disabled/greyed out. But in this status, the samples seem to work.

At least, I could get the simple and stream app to work this way.

**Edit / Solution:**

Ok, I got it working now. I found that I copy/pasted the wrong key hash, due to some weird behaviour of keytool under windows and a wrong command syntax in the ReadMe file of the Facebook SDK.

The parameter to be used should be "`keytool -export ...`" and not "`keytool -exportcert ...`"; if you do use the second/wrong parameter, keytool would still print out a hash key (withouth asking for any key password though), but the hash is wrong.

Now I got SSO working as well.

This is my call on windows:

```
keytool -export -alias androiddebugkey -keystore "C:\Documents and Settings\myuser\.android\debug.keystore" | openssl sha1 -binary | openssl enc -a -e
```

Comment: This works but is unfortunately not a solution. If I understand it correctly Single-logon means that it should work without signing in, and just ask for permission. If the single-login does not exist on device then it will fall back on the simple web-view.

I guess if I uninstall the updates the single login thins is deactivated and I have to login. Which means that the example app will work. So if I'm right I must do something else wrong.

Comment: I understand it as you, but also didn't get it to work. Please update if you get any news on it, will do the same.

Comment: I worked out a fix, I simply commented out lines in the method that checks for single sign on in the Facebook class. The method is after:

    public void authorize(Activity activity, String[] permissions,
            int activityCode, final DialogListener listener) {
        mAuthDialogListener = listener;
            startDialogAuth(activity, permissions);
    }

Comment: However this is not ideal since the single addon, still is not working. But at least now you can login in and it's usable. There still needs to be a solution to the original problem.

Comment: I will post it to the Facebook github, see if we get some reply.

Comment: Please upvote the issue here: https://github.com/facebook/facebook-android-sdk/issues/issue/144

Comment: @Joakim: I found the reason/solution, check out my edited reply.

Comment: I got it working. But with my mac, there seems to be something wrong with the windows parameters, or the way I wrote it on windows.

Answer (score 0):

I tried on windows as per your solution using both export and exportcert but it generates same Hash. Application now works as earlier and not using the the new SSO way.

I debugged android FB SDK ,i found the cause but not exact the solution. Don't know why facebook guys implemented SSO this way.

1. SSO does not work, if you don't have FB app new update installed on your android phone.
2. In this case,  It routes to the regular dialog interface with user name and password.

3.In details, FB Android SDK to handle SSO, is calling an intent com.facebook.katana.ProxyAuth it return true if it update is available.

1. If user have new update and already logged in. then it validates user.

Hope this will help.