# Facebook login fails on some devices

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-login

I have implemented the Facebook login and it works fine on some devices/AVDs. My development device is a Gingerbread phone, but testing it with a 4.1.1 device, it simply does not log in. After pressing the facebook button, it shows a blank screen (trying to connect Facebook), and after 1-2 seconds it comes back to the home screen. Also, no errors are toasted or displayed in the Logcat. Oh, and the Facebook application is installed in the device... Any ideas?

**UPDATE:**

I enabled logging as suggested by Mark Venzke and using [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16068033/1188554) procedure, and I got this warning (twice) on every login attempt (note: testing with a HTC One S phone):

```
07-05 20:14:50.582: W/PackageManager(605): Unable to load service info ResolveInfo{4171dbf0 com.htc.socialnetwork.facebook.remote.FacebookSyncService p=0 o=0 m=0x108000}
```

Note the com.htc.socialnetwork.facebook.remote.FacebookSyncService line, so is there any extra step needed for HTC devices?

Also, I'm attaching the code where the login is performed:

```
private void onSessionStateChange(Session session, SessionState state, Exception exception) {
    if (isResumed) {
        FragmentManager manager = getSupportFragmentManager();
        int backStackSize = manager.getBackStackEntryCount();
        for (int i = 0; i < backStackSize; i++) {
            manager.popBackStack();
        }
        com.facebook.Settings.addLoggingBehavior(LoggingBehavior.REQUESTS);
        if (state.isOpened()) {

            Bundle params = new Bundle();
            params.putString("fields", "id");
            params.putString("limit", "1");             
            Request request = new Request(Session.getActiveSession(), "me", params, HttpMethod.GET, new Callback()
            {

                @Override
                public void onCompleted(Response response)
                {
                    if (response != null)
                    {
                        Log.d("AuthGraphResponse", response.toString());
                        long id;
                        try {
                            id = response.getGraphObject().getInnerJSONObject().getLong("id");
                            app.setFacebookId(id);
                            Log.d("UserID", Long.valueOf(id).toString());
                        } catch (JSONException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                    }
                }
            });

            RequestAsyncTask task = new RequestAsyncTask(request);
            task.execute();

            showFragment(AUTH, false);
        } else if (state.isClosed()) {
            showFragment(UNAUTH, false);
        }
    }
}
```

**UPDATE 2:**

Is it possible that HTC renames the package name of the default Facebook application in all the devices (or some of them, whatever) to com.htc.socialnetwork.facebook (instead of com.facebook.katana) and it leads to this conflict? I don't really think that uninstalling the default app and installing Facebook from Google Play is an acceptable solution (also, I think default apps cannot be uninstalled).

**UPDATE 3:**

Not solved yet. 19 hours to award the 100 reputation bounty!

**UPDATE 4:**

Another interesting line of the LogCat:

```
07-15 10:55:51.718: E/chromium(30475): external/chromium/net/disk_cache/stat_hub.cc:216: [0715/105551:ERROR:stat_hub.cc(216)] StatHub::Init - App com.facebook.katana isn't supported.
```

Comment: [stressed mode on] sometimes you have just to assume that Facebook SDK (at least the latest) is really damn buggy and will crash a lot. Which SDK are you using?

Comment: yes! i see that facebook is not really good at mobile, generally speaking (their own apps also suck a lot)... i am using the latest sdk, which appears to be v3.0.1. If this is a bug of the sdk, it's been there for 3 months!

Comment: The SDK works differently when FB native app is installed on phone or not.. are you considering this scenario?

Comment: I actually thought it wouldnt work without the fb native app. But anyway, i tested it having it installed

Comment: Can you post some code please?

Comment: You need to post code in order for people to post relavant answers.

Comment: oops, forgot to announce it here, i updated the question :)

Comment: Can you provide the rest of the Facebook SDK Log output (removing any personal data)? It's possible the FacebookSyncService line is unrelated, or at least the rest of the info would help provide context.

Comment: ok, i will, but tomorrow (i don't have that phone right now). Anyway, another interesting line of the logcat I noticed today is: E/chromium(30475): external/chromium/net/disk_cache/stat_hub.cc:216: [0715/105551:ERROR:stat_hub.cc(216)] StatHub::Init - App com.facebook.katana isn't supported.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is certainly a conflict between your stock app and the SDK. So if you don't want to uninnstall the stock HTC app and still use the SDK 3.0 I think your best bet without modying the source code of the sdk would be to disable SSO and login only through webview.

This can easily be done by adding the SessionLoginBehavior.SUPRESS_SSO everytime you try to open a new session. Here is a sample I changed from the SessionLoginSample (LoginUsingActivityActivity) from the Facebook SDK to show you what to do :

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    ...
    Session session = Session.getActiveSession();
    if (session == null) {
        if (savedInstanceState != null) {
            session = Session.restoreSession(this, null, statusCallback, savedInstanceState);
        }
        if (session == null) {
            session = new Session(this);
        }
        Session.setActiveSession(session);

        //add the check, for if session is opened
        if (session.getState().equals(SessionState.CREATED_TOKEN_LOADED) || !session.getState().isOpened()) {
            //Add the suppress SSO behavior to force webview auth dialog to popup
            session.openForRead(new Session.OpenRequest(this).setCallback(statusCallback).setLoginBehavior(SessionLoginBehavior.SUPPRESS_SSO));
        }
    }
  ...
}
//then put your code in the statusCallback method or keep it in the session state change listener
```

Otherwise if you don't mind changing the facebook sdk code, you should check [this](https://github.com/Thuzi/Android-Facebook-Authentication) out

Comment: +1 Got the same problem. Thanks for pointing out the conflict with HTC stock app. I got it working by setting behavior on facebook's LoginButton instance: `authButton.setLoginBehavior(SessionLoginBehavior.SUPPRESS_SSO)`

Answer (score 4):

Shirley Facebook login is not broken on all 4.1.1 devices, so it is something with your implementation.

Are you sure the Key Hash is the same on that device as what you have configured on developer.facebook.com? If you used a different dev key, or it was installed by a third-party store, it's possible the key hashes don't match.

Turn on debug logging in the Facebook SDK source code and rebuild it. It is generally off by default for security reasons. Depending on your version of the SDK, it may be in Util.java or some other location, and may be a variable called 'ENABLE_LOG'.

Answer (score 2):

I think facebook login error mostly occur so to solve this issue you follow there tutorial step by step again with patience.

Other wise its very difficult to solve your problem here. So you can refer this link.

http://developers.facebook.com/android/

I hope you will success.

Answer (score 1):

There isn't enough info in your question. so, I'm making a few guesses here.

1)First look into Mike Venzke's answer.

2) If this doesn't work then try this:
You need to sign in on you device using SSO (Single Sign On). So here are the steps you can take.

delete the build. reinstall it. and when asked for permissions from your device, allow them.

If you aren't taken back to your app then you need to add these to your manifest file:

```
<activity
        android:name="com.facebook.LoginActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
    </activity>
<meta-data android:value="@string/app_id" android:name="com.facebook.sdk.ApplicationId"/>
```

where app_name and app_id are your respective app Id and app name on your Facebook app page.

Have you added these btw?

you need these permission as well

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
```

if you post some more info I might be guess the issue.

Comment: I already had all that configured in the manifest (except the first 2 permissions, though I added them and got the same behaviour). Also, note that this is actually working in my usual device (ZTE Skate, Gingerbread). I updated the post, I'm getting what it seems an HTC specific error (not working on HTC One S).

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem with your Facebook android app in device. So first uninstall the facebook android app from device and check that facebook login working properly or not.

Comment: Nope. Tested on 2 HTC One S devices and both give the same result

Answer (score 1):

Since Honeycomb you are not able to make internet calls on the main thread, try using an Android AsyncTask or creating a new thread yourself.

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html

Comment: RequestAsyncTask (look at the code) is a Facebook class that theoretically runs on an AsyncTask, so the network call should not be made in the UI thread

Comment: Well, maybe it will help, but anyway, found that com.htc.socialnetwork.facebook is the stock facebook for some htc devices and removing it and installing from the Play Store maybe will help you...

Comment: what do you mean with "com.htc.socialnetwork.facebook is the stock facebook for some htc devices"? So, uninstalling and re-installing Facebook from Google Play should solve this?

Comment: Sorry, I am not sure anymore, but probably the problem is with your Facebook for HTC service, try clearing the data or deleting your sync account, probably it will remove your friends pictures from your contacts but may help.

Answer (score 0):

I got this error when using a device with an old version of facebook. Removing facebook completely, or updating the facebook app fixed it.

I'm pretty sure this happens because Facebook for Android used to be just a wrapped WebView of the mobile site.

Also note that some devices (my Incredible 4G LTE) will reinstall the old (webview) version of facebook if you try to remove it.

Answer (score 0):

connect device to eclipse to see logcat. if log cat not running open cmd prompt in windows and run adb restart, (set the adb path first). then you can see logcat running. now open your app and click facebook login button. you can get the correct hash key in yellow colour in log cat. put that key on facebook and now facebook login will work on every device. thanks.

Answer (score 0):

```
List<String> permissions = new ArrayList<String>();
permissions.add("email");



//start Facebook session
openActiveSession(this, true, new Session.StatusCallback() {
    @Override
    public void call(Session session, SessionState state, Exception exception) {
        if (session.isOpened()) {
            //make request to the /me API

            Request.executeMeRequestAsync(session, new Request.GraphUserCallback() {
                @Override
                public void onCompleted(GraphUser user, Response response) {
                    if (user != null) {
                        String firstName = user.getFirstName();
                        String lastName = user.getLastName();
                        String id = user.getId();
                        String email=null;
                        try {
                            email = user.getProperty("email").toString();
                        } catch (Exception e) {
                            // TODO: handle exception
                        }

                        String gender = (String) user.getProperty("gender");
                        String birthday = user.getBirthday();



                    //welcome.setText("Hello \n" + firstName+"\n"+lastName+"\n"+email+"\n"+gender+"\n"+birthday+"!");




                    if(firstName!=null)
                    {


                          SharedPreferences.Editor editor = settings.edit();

                            editor.putString("fligin", "1");
                            editor.putString("firstName", firstName);
                            editor.putString("lastName", lastName);
                            editor.putString("email", email);
                            editor.putString("gender", gender);
                            editor.putString("birthday", birthday);
                            editor.commit();

                        Intent intent=new Intent(getApplicationContext(), RegistrationOneActivity.class);
                        startActivity(intent);
                        //overridePendingTransition( R.anim.slide_in_up, R.anim.slide_out_up );

                        finish();
                    }
                    else {

                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Person information is null", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                    finish();
                        }



                    }
                }
            });
         }
     }
 }, permissions);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try inserting this line where you define your login button in the java source code

```
LoginButton fb_button = (LoginButton)findViewById(//your resource id);
fb_button.setLoginBehavior(SessionLoginBehavior.SUPPRESS_SSO);
```

Comment: Try inserting 4 spaces in front of the two lines to format the code.