# Convert code from Google Map Android API v1 to Google Map Android API v2?

Tags: android, google-maps

This is code `Google Map Android API v1`. I don't know convert to `API v2`. Help me, please!

FlatBack.java

```
public class FlatBack extends MapActivity {
private MapView mapView;
private MyLocationOverlay myLocationOverlay;


@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    setContentView(R.layout.map);

    mapView = (MapView) findViewById(R.id.mapView);
    mapView.setBuiltInZoomControls(true);

    myLocationOverlay = new FixLocation(this, mapView);

    mapView.getOverlays().add(myLocationOverlay);
    mapView.postInvalidate();

    zoomToMyLocation();
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.map_toggle, menu);
    return true;
}

public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
    case R.id.map:
        if (mapView.isSatellite() == true) {
            mapView.setSatellite(false);
            mapView.setStreetView(true);
        }
        return true;
    case R.id.sat:
        if (mapView.isSatellite() == false) {
            mapView.setSatellite(true);
            mapView.setStreetView(false);
        }
        return true;
    case R.id.both:
        mapView.setSatellite(true);
        mapView.setStreetView(true);
    default:
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}

@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    myLocationOverlay.enableMyLocation();
}

@Override
protected void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
    myLocationOverlay.disableMyLocation();
}

private void zoomToMyLocation() {
    GeoPoint myLocationGeoPoint = myLocationOverlay.getMyLocation();
    if (myLocationGeoPoint != null) {
        mapView.getController().animateTo(myLocationGeoPoint);
        mapView.getController().setZoom(10);
    }
}

protected boolean isRouteDisplayed() {
    return false;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Finally, the most important is to add *Google Play Services* as an Android library project as follows:

- Select *File > Import > Android > Existing Android Code Into Workspace* and click *Next*. Select *Browse...*, enter */extras/google/google_play_services/libproject/google-play-services_lib*, and click *Finish*.
- Check if the *libs/* folder containing the `android-support-v4.jar` exists in your project.
- `android-support-v4.jar` is located in `/extras/android/compatibility/v4/android-support-v4.jar` under your "android-sdk" drectory.

Before running your project, you must set your project Build target to "Google APIs", not Android x.x. version : Select your project and click *Project > Properties > Project Build Target* in Eclipse and select any "Google APIs ", and then run your project on your phone. If you use the emulator, also **must** set the AVD of the emulator to the any "Google APIs ".

- Follow this article: [Map Fragment / MapView v2 Quick Start](https://docs.google.com/document/pub?id=19nQzvKP-CVLd7_VrpwnHfl-AE9fjbJySowONZZtNHzw)
- [map v2 article](http://karnshah8890.blogspot.in/2013/02/google-maps-android-api-v2-introduction.html)
- [google-maps-android-api-v2-introduction](http://karnshah8890.blogspot.in/2013/02/google-maps-android-api-v2-introduction.html)

Comment: Thanks you very much. But everything which you guide above that I done. However, MapView shows empty. :-(

Comment: it's probably blank because of the wrong API key. Mapview uses MD5 fingerprint, Maps v2 needs SHA fingerprint, use keytool command to obtain it, or use code (it's in the answer in here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13966906/app-is-misconfigured-for-facebook-login-not-returning-the-logcat-after-setti)